# How does C# 3.0 jagged array performance optimization vs. rectangular arrays work?

Tags: c#, arrays, optimization, jagged-arrays

In the Apress book "Illustrated C# 2008", pg. 343 notes:

> "One-dimensional arrays have specific instructions in the CIL that allow them 
>   to be optimized for performance.  Rectangular arrays do not have these
>   instructions...Because of this, it can sometimes be more efficient to use
>   jagged arrays..."

Does anyone know how these performance optimizations are implemented?

Comment: Read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/arrays.aspx). Note that it's written about version 1.0 of the CLR; I don't know how much has changed since.

Comment: Thanks!  One change appears to be that jagged arrays are now CLS compliant (see: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=94823), while the CodeProject document states: "...jagged arrays are not CLS-compliant...".

Comment: The CodeProject article links to this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163995.aspx). Although it's from 2004, it does include code for benchmarking jagged vs. rectangular arrays for both sequential and diagonal access.