# How to optimize this nested for loop where the most overhead is from the multi dimensional array index lookup

Tags: c#

for example

```
 for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
   for (int j=0;j<100;j++)
     for (int k=0;k<100;k++)
       for (int l=0;l<100;l++)
         for (int m=0;m<100;m++)
  {
     DoSth(myArray[i,j,k,l,m]);
  }
```

I tried to convert 5dimensional myArray into int[][][][][] myJaggedArray, it is still slow.

Is there any way I can improve it?
Note:  the most overhead comes from the multi dimensional array index lookup

There is one ugly way i can think of:  (e.g. 2 nested loop)

```
for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
 {
   var tmp = myJaggedArray[i];
   {
     for (int j=0;j<100;j++)
     {
      DoSth(tmp[j]);
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: How to optimize it depends on what you are doing this for.

Comment: If you truly need a 5dimensional array and need to access every member of said array then you will end up with this same amount of calls no matter the implementation.  A custom iterator would at least prevent you from having to use 5 nested for loops multiple times in your code every time you need to loop through the values.

Comment: Your edits have *completely* changed the question... without any comment or indication that you've done so.

Comment: @JonSkeet: sry, I am still thinking of a best way to abstract my problem. It is reverted back now

Comment: @colinfang: Just when I've edited my answer to take account of the changes... I'm afraid when you just keep changing it with no actual context (like the size of the array, or what you're trying to achieve) there's not a lot of point in me continuing. Hopefully the answer I've already provided will help, but if not, ping me a comment when you've made the question more answerable (and are content not to change it any further).

Answer (score 3):

Simply put: don't use a multi-dimensional array if you can help it and if you really need the speed. They're significantly slower to access than single-dimensional arrays. I don't know how much difference there is between "rank 2" and "rank 5", but the difference between *vectors* (always 0-based, single-dimensional) and *arrays* (arbitrary base, can be multi-dimensional) if pretty big.

It looks like you're iterating over the whole array in the obvious order, so just keep it as a single-dimensional array instead. Mind you, as if this is an `int` array that's 40GB of data. Do you *really* have that much data, and is it all in physical memory rather than swapping?

EDIT: Okay, now that you've completely changed the question... you can *start* by not refetching `a[i]`, `b[j]` on every iteration (which could be having severe cache implications):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int ai = a[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        int bj = b[j];
        for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
        {
            int ck = c[k];
            for (int l = 0; l < 100; l++)
            {
                dl = d[l];
                for (int m = 0; m < 100; m++)
                {
                    int em = e[m];
                    DoSomething(myArray[ai, bj, ck, dl, em]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using a jagged array as per your question would *also* help, but could have significant memory implications. Another alternative is to have a single-dimensional array, and work out the "base index" at each level of your loop.

Comment: Infact, there is no apparently ways to optimise array acess, OP concerns about,  but *iteration* flow.

Comment: When Jon answers a question I was going to respond to, it feels like someone just said over the radio "Good morning, gentlemen, the temperature is 110 degrees." :-)  I would just add to ensure that you access your flattened array in row major order.  That can make a huge difference in performance due to elements being next to each other in cache.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

Answer (score 1):

Give the Jitter a chance to optimize:

```
for (int i=0; i < myArray.GetLength(0);i++)
   for (int j=0; j < myArray.GetLength(1);j++)
     for (int k=0; k < myArray.GetLength(2);k++)
       for (int l=0; l < myArray.GetLength(3);l++)
         for (int m=0; m < myArray.GetLength(4);m++)
  {
     DoSth(myArray[i,j,k,l,m]);
  }
```

This will speed up a jagged array more than this case.

And at the very least it's easier to maintain.

---

The real speed up case:

```
int[][][] myArray = ...; // create it
....


for (int i=0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
   subArray1 = myArray[i];
   for (int j=0; j < subArray1.Length; j++)
   {
     subArray2 = subArray2[j];
     for (int k=0; k < subArray2.Length; k++)
     {
        subArray2[k] = ...
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: could u provide some keywords i can search for this technique? i am quite interested in it.

Comment: It has to do with range-checking. Which is your real problem, not the lookup. Here is [one (of many) SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1986989/60761).

Comment: however, from my reading here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/08/13/array-bounds-check-elimination-in-the-clr.aspx multi-dimensional array won't eliminate range check

Comment: Correct, it is more aimed at the jagged arrays. I copied some code that was available. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
foreach (int x in myArray) {
    DoSth(x);
}
```

---

As Jon Skeet says, your array is HUGE! If it contains mainly nulls, you should consider an alternative approach. You could use a dictionary to store the values.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<long,int>();

if (value != 0) {
    long index = (((i * 100 + j) * 100 + k) * 100 + l) * 100 + m;
    dict[index] = value;
}
```

---

It would be best to use a helper function to calculate the index

```
public long Index(int i, int j, int k, int l, int m)
{
    return (((i * 100 + j) * 100 + k) * 100 + l) * 100 + m;
}
```

```
dict[Index(i,j,k,l,m)] = value;

int result;
if (dict.TryGetValue(Index(i,j,k,l,m), out result)) {
    DoSth(result);
}
```

Or

```
foreach (int value in dict.Values) {
    DoSth(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array is **sparse** (many zeroes), a dictionary with `Tuple` as key will be much faster:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, int, int int>, int>();

// Add element
dict[new Tuple(i,j,k,l,m)] = value;

// Get element
value = dict[new Tuple(i,j,k,l,m)];

// Traverse
foreach(var kv in dict)
{
     // You can always get the indexes if you need to
     int i = kv.Key.Item1;
     int j = kv.Key.Item2;
     int k = kv.Key.Item3;
     int l = kv.Key.Item4;
     int m = kv.Key.Item5;

     // ...Or do something
     DoSomething(kv.Value);
}
```

Comment: can i replace the `Tuple` with int[5]?